# 401 error when Azure AD web API method called in console application

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have tried other answers before I post this question.

I have created a web API and published into azure web app. I have enabled azure AD authentication. I have created one app registration and given permissions to AD app. In my console application, I am calling as below:

```
private static async Task<string> GetToken()
        {

            string aadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/common";
            string ResourceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceId"];
            string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"];
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
            string replyAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReplyAddressConfigured"];
            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Password"];
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =
              new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(aadInstance, tenantId));
            PlatformParameters k = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);            
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceId, clientId, new Uri(replyAddress),k).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        } 

static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
           var accessToken = await GetToken();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetData/GetLicensing?appName=test&tenantId=f556301-8a1e-48c3-b59e-55a9036f843e");
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    readTask.Wait();                   
                }
            }
        }
```

`IsSuccessStatusCode` code is coming as false with 401. What is the mistake here. But if I use client and secret it is successful. It is not possible to call without passing `client secret` value?
Below is just illustration:
[image]

Comment: Share the full response body please. 401 can happen for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot get correct token without client secret if you are calling the API without using [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)**.

But, if you use [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet), in both API and hosted Console app on cloud, you can call API from the Console app without Client secret.